# How to stop spacebar popup qcombobox in python

Tags: python, pyqt5, qcombobox

By default qcombobox performs inline autocompletion and this is working fine
but when the item contains a space the spacebar keypress popup the qcombobox
how can i disable this and let the space key used in the inline autocompletion
i have tried using complete with this code

```
self.ui.comboBox_ui_3.setEditable(True)
self.ui.comboBox_ui_3.completer().setCompletionMode(QCompleter.InlineCompletion)
self.ui.comboBox_ui_3.setInsertPolicy(QComboBox.NoInsert)
```

but this is not performing as expected as it allows user in enter letters in the editable line thats not in your list

Comment: By "inline autocompletion" do you mean the keyboard search that selects an item based on what's typed even if the combo is *not* editable?

Comment: yes, exactly, but just hitting a space it is not autocompleting anymore and it pops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the spacebar is pressed, the `keyPressEvent` of QComboBox is called, and if it is not editable it automatically shows the popup (the same happens with <kbd>F4</kbd> and <kbd>Alt+↓</kbd>). If another key is pressed and that key is not used for "keyboard navigation" such as the arrow keys, the keyboard search (*not* "autocompletion", which is a completely different thing) is activated.

Keyboard search uses the [`keyboardSearch()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#keyboardSearch) function of the popup, so the solution is to implement a similar method.

This can be achieved with a subclass:

```
class MyCombo(QtWidgets.QComboBox):
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Space:
            # get the QModelIndex of the underlying model
            currentModelIndex = self.model().index(
                self.currentIndex(), self.modelColumn(), self.rootModelIndex())
            # get the popup view, which uses the same model
            view = self.view()
            # set the model index on the view
            view.setCurrentIndex(currentModelIndex)
            # call the keyboard search with the space character
            view.keyboardSearch(' ')
        else:
            # use the default implementation if any other key is pressed
            super().keyPressEvent(event)
```

Since you are probably using an UI generated by designer, the easiest solution would be to install an event filter on the combo. The implementation is almost the same.

```
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.ui.comboBox_ui_3.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if source == self.ui.comboBox_ui_3 and event.type() == event.KeyPress:
            if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Space:
                currentModelIndex = source.model().index(
                    source.currentIndex(), source.modelColumn(), source.rootModelIndex())
                view = source.view()
                view.setCurrentIndex(currentModelIndex)
                view.keyboardSearch(' ')
                return True
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)
```

Comment: Looks working with ui i think as it is not popping anymore with spacebar but once i hit space it searches for a word starting with letter after hitting the space key

Comment: maybe it something with search timeout ?

Comment: @HoussamFarag sorry but I cannot understand what you mean, can you try to be more clear?

Comment: i am searching for an item like fried chicken, once i type fried and hit space it starts getting items starting with c( the first letter in chicken), i think this something with typing speed ?

Comment: @HoussamFarag the keyboard search uses the first exact match *after* the current, and the space character acts exactly as any other character. If your items are `["a", "ax"]` and `"a"` is the current, if you press "a" right afterwards it will select the second. The same happens for the spacebar: if in your items you have "fried" and "fried chicken", when you press the spacebar after typing "fried", it obviously returns the first match that starts with "fried " (with a space).

Comment: You're welcome. Remember that if my answer were useful to you and it solved your issue, you should set it as accepted by clicking on the check mark on its left.

Comment: i am really sorry as the website refused my vote

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: @HoussamFarag To accept an answer you don't have to click on the "up arrow", but on the ✓ (check mark) symbol.

Comment: Done , your solution was very inspiring , thanks a lot